# How did Maggie get to the hilltop?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Near the start of Season 7 when Negan stops by Alexandria the first time the group implies to Negan that Maggie is dead and didn't survive the return trip. In reality she has somehow been brought to the hilltop.

Did they ever explain how Maggie got to the hilltop? The timelines seem pretty tight here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sasha took her

At the end of Season 7 Episode 1 - *The Day Will Come When You Won't Be* after Negan has left the group Maggie is told that she still needs to go to Hilltop for treatment. She says that she is taking Glenn's body, Sasha says she will take her.

From the script:

> **Rick:** Maggie.
>   Maggie.
>   [Sobs] Maggie you need to sit down.
>   Maggie.
>
> **Maggie:** No.
>
> **Rick:** We need to get you to the Hilltop.
>
> **Maggie:** You need to go get ready.
>
> **Rick:** For what?
>
> **Maggie:** To fight them.
>
> **Rick: ** They have Daryl.
>   They have an army.
>   [Breathing heavily] We would die -- all of us.
>
> **Maggie:** Go home.
>   [Voice breaking] Take everybody with you.
>   I can get there by myself.
>
> **Rick:** You can barely stand up.
>
> **Maggie:** I need to go.
>   You need to go to Alexandria.
>   [Breathing heavily] You were out -- out here for me.
>
> **Rick:**  We still are.
>
> **Maggie:** [Sobbing] I can make it now.
>   I need you to go back.
>   I can't have you out here.
>   I can't have you all out here anymore.
>   I need you to go back.
>
> **Rick:**  Maggie we're not letting you go.
>   Okay?
>
> **Maggie:** You have to.
>   [Sighs] It's not gonna happen.
>
> **Sasha:** [Breathing heavily] I'm taking her.
>   I'm gonna get her there.
>   I'm gonna keep her safe.
>   I'm not giving you a choice.
>   I'm taking him with me.
>   [Groans] I'm gonna take him.
>   [Voice breaking] That's what I'm gonna do.

Answer (score 2):

Sasha takes her. it is clearly stated in the episode 1 or 2.

Here you see the both of them by Glens grave in Hilltop.

Behind  them is the grave of Abraham.

[image]